# Sync old phone messages for 2 different outlook accounts

Tags: sync, transfer

I want to retrieve my old phone (Nokia Lumia 530) text message to my new phone (Microsoft Lumia 535).

I have used the option transfer my data but it is showing me o**nly option to transfer the contacts and no other thing like text messages…**

It seems that there is some security issue or somewhat due to 2 different outlook accounts.

**I am using 2 different outlook accounts.**

Please suggest me if there is any option available online on Microsoft site to view all my old messages.

Comment: Did you set the new phone up witht he same primary account as your previous phone? Had you used the back-up feature to back the messages up?

Comment: @RowlandShaw, Actually I have not used same email Id. I have used 2 different email ids.

Answer (score 2):

If you set your new phone with the same id as the primary id from your previous phone, then during setup you'll get the chance to restore data from your last backup, as well as things like your start screen layout, and installed apps.

The only way to change the primary id is to perform a hard reset which will lose all the data that you've accumulated since then (i.e. messages you've recieved and backed up since you changed phone)

Comment: I am agree with you but I can not change my primary Id as I have some offers associated with this. I will loose if I change my email Id. That's why I am looking for some way to merge 2 email ids or cross email ids data backup.